# MasterPanel.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ventana'

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un sistema de logeo y cuando el usuario hace el login (que funciona perfecto) y manda al usuario al archivo principal donde podrá visualizar la app me salta el error MasterPanel.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ventana', por lo que entiendo el error es porque el **init** solamente agarra la primer variable que se le asigna, pero en verdad no se como resolverlo.

Antes me funcionaba perfecto, pero cuando pase el archivo al proyecto donde esta el sistema de login me empezó a agarrar el error, creo que debe ser porque interfiere con algo (Tal vez es un error tonto pero estoy aprendiendo a utilizar python :p)
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import BOLD
import util.generic as utl
from tkinter.ttk import Scale
from tkinter import colorchooser,filedialog,messagebox
import PIL.ImageGrab as ImageGrab

class MasterPanel():
    def __init__(self,ventana):      
# Menu
        menu = Menu(ventana)
        File = Menu(menu)
        Help = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label= 'File', menu = File)
        menu.add_cascade(label= 'Help', menu = Help)
# Configuración de la ventana
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.ventana.title("Gech BOX Studio - Canvas - (Alpha) v1.0.0")
        self.ventana.iconbitmap("logo.ico")
        self.ventana.geometry("1100x600+30+50")
        self.ventana.resizable(0,0)
        self.ventana.config(menu=menu)




# Vars   
        self.pointer= "black"
        self.erase="white"

    
        text=Text(ventana)

        self.gechv = Label(self.ventana,bg='gray15',height=900,width=1000)
        self.gechv.place(x=100,y=0)

        self.pick_color = LabelFrame(self.ventana,font =('arial',15),bd=0,relief=RIDGE,bg="gray23")
        self.pick_color.place(x=25,y=25,width=50,height=185)

        colors = ['black','gray17','red', 'yellow','green','blue','Purple1','RosyBrown1','white','gray','orange','gold','dark green','royal blue','SlateBlue1','Salmon1']
        i=j=0
        for color in colors:
            Button(self.pick_color,bg=color,bd=0,relief=RIDGE,width=3,command=lambda col=color:self.select_color(col)).grid(row=i,column=j)
            i+=1
            if i==8:
                i=0
                j=1

        self.eraser_btn= Button(self.ventana,text="Eraser",bg='gray30',fg="White",command=self.eraser,width=9,height=1,relief=RIDGE)
        self.eraser_btn.place(x=15,y=220)

        self.clear_screen= Button(self.ventana,text="Clear",bg='gray30',fg="White",command= lambda : self.background.delete('all'),width=9,height=1,relief=RIDGE)
        self.clear_screen.place(x=15,y=250)

        self.save_btn= Button(self.ventana,text="Export",bg='gray30',fg="White",command=self.save_drawing,width=9,height=1,relief=RIDGE)
        self.save_btn.place(x=15,y=280)

        self.bg_btn= Button(self.ventana,text="Background",bg='gray30',fg="White",command=self.canvas_color,width=9,height=1,relief=RIDGE)
        self.bg_btn.place(x=15,y=310)

        self.pointer_frame= LabelFrame(self.ventana,bd=0,bg="gray23",font=('arial',15,'bold'),relief=RIDGE)
        self.pointer_frame.place(x=25,y=370,height=200,width=70)

        self.pointer_size =Scale(self.pointer_frame,orient=VERTICAL,from_ =88 , to =0, length=200)
        self.pointer_size.set(1)
        self.pointer_size.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=15)

        self.background = Canvas(self.ventana,bg='white',relief=GROOVE,height=550,width=960)
        self.background.config(cursor="circle")
        self.background.place(x=120,y=25)

#Bind the background Canvas with mouse click
        self.background.bind("<B1-Motion>",self.paint) 


    def paint(self,event):       
        x1,y1 = (event.x-2), (event.y-2)  
        x2,y2 = (event.x+2), (event.y+2)  

        self.background.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill=self.pointer,outline=self.pointer,width=self.pointer_size.get())

    def select_color(self,col):
        self.pointer = col

    def eraser(self):
        self.pointer= self.erase
  
    def canvas_color(self):
        color=colorchooser.askcolor()
        self.background.configure(background=color[1])
        self.erase= color[1]

    def save_drawing(self):
        try:
            # self.background update()
            file_ss =filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='jpg')
            #print(file_ss)
            x=self.ventana.winfo_ventanax() + self.background.winfo_x()
            #print(x, self.background.winfo_x())
            y=self.ventana.winfo_ventanay() + self.background.winfo_y()
            #print(y)

            x1= x + self.background.winfo_width() 
            #print(x1)
            y1= y + self.background.winfo_height()
            #print(y1)
            ImageGrab.grab().crop((x , y, x1, y1)).save(file_ss)
            messagebox.showinfo('Screenshot Successfully Saved as' + str(file_ss))
            msgalert = ventana(text="Hola")
            msgalert.pack()

        except:
            print("Error in saving the screenshot")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    ventana = Tk()
    p = MasterPanel(ventana)
    ventana.mainloop()
```

```
TypeError: MasterPanel.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ventana'
```

Comment: Por qué la definición de la clase tiene `MasterPanel()`? Será que eso interfiere de alguna forma con el constructor?

Answer (score 0):

El error que comentas no tiene mucha pérdida, por lo que me extraña el error que te aparece. Cuando te pasen este tipo de cosas, te recomiendo buscar el error de forma escalada, de lo más sencillo a lo más complicado. Por ejemplo:

```
# Comentar todos los imports innecesarios
class MasterPanel():
    def __init__(self, ventana):
        print(ventana)
        return # no ejecutar más llamadas a módulos, etc, que pueden dificultar el debugging

# Comentar el resto del código, de momento  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ventana = 'prueba'
    p = MasterPanel(ventana)
```

Te diría que, a partir de aquí, donde esto funciona, fueras descomentando progresivamente partes de tu código, hasta encontrar el punto concreto donde falla.

Otra posibilidad podría ser que hayas cambiado el constructor de la clase `MasterPanel`, y no se haya reflejado correctamente cuando lo estás ejecutando.